# How to edit the shortcut for runnig code in visual studio code with code runner (Ctrl+Alt+N)

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

How can I change the shortcut used in visual studio code after installing code runner. Current shortcut `Ctrl+Alt+N`. I want to change it to something like `F5` or `Switch + Enter` or any other easier one.

[image]

This is how to run the code:

[image]

How can I change that shortcut?

Comment: just add an additional key binding to `F5` for that command

Comment: @rioV8 and how can i do that

Comment: read the doc page on key bindings

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Go to settings
   ----(On the bottom left of your screen on vs code, click on the cog)
2. Click on keyboard shortcuts
3. Search the term "Run code" in the search bar
   ----(you'll see the text "code-runner.run" under the command)
4. Hover over this field and then either right click or click on the pencil icon that shows up to change keybinding
5. Change details and enter

Alternatively you could directly search up the keys involved in the shortcut. Here you could have searched up the term "ctrl alt n" to get to your command in a more convenient fashion
----(if you do not know which keywords are associated with your particular shortcut, then you may just search up the interfering keys)

Comment: Life saver on non-English keyboards - thx.